# SQL Query second relation

Tags: sql

i have a problem i want to take SQL query language that returns the employee's (id) supervisor to his supervisor.

I have a tab employee

```
create table employee (
    id int not null,
    surname varchar(50),
    name varchar(30),
    boss_id int)
```

Comment: complete your question...what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: Add some sample data with your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

```
  select a.id, b.boss_id
  from employee as a 
  inner join employee as b on a.boss_id=b.id
```

For test case

```
create table DemoTable
(
    accountid bigint
    ,parentid bigint
    ,accountname nvarchar(128)
)
insert DemoTable(accountid,parentid,accountname)
select 1, null, 'Root'
union select 2, 3, 'Child1'
union select 3, 1, 'Child2'
```

Query:

```
select a.accountid, b.parentid from DemoTable as a 
inner join DemoTable as b on a.parentid=b.accountid
```

output is as : pass `accountid as 2`

```
accountid   parentid
   2           1
```

Here `2  >>  3  >>  1`

Comment: This query will give only the employee_id and his supervisor while OP needs supervisor's supervisor.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai test it again